# how to add favicon to AEM assets such as pdf / videos

Tags: aem

we have a site wholly hosted on AEM and apache webserver. We are facing an issue where the web pages are displaying favicon.ico correctly but the same are not getting displayed on pdfs and videos.

On searching online, we found that keeping favicon in root folder should resolve the issue or keeping in /etc/designs/default can help in resolving the issue, but none of them are working.

Due to this issue, we are getting lot of 404 error logs almost 10K per day. Please help in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version von AEM do you use? Are you sure that you mean favicon? Have you a working example for those scenario? As far as I know favicon.ico must be explicit included in an html page. Can you provide  a screenshot that is not working?

Comment: Can you paste example of those PDF and Video URLs here so that it can be investigated further?